# Mod Rewrite not working at all, everything else in the .htaccess works correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .htaccess, apache-2.4

This must be the 100th time a topic with this name has been created however this time its slightly different. I am trying to use mod_rewrite to enable Short URLs on a MediaWiki install.

I have added the following to apache2.conf and 000-default.conf in the correct places:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

I have tested that the module is loaded:

```
Loaded Modules
core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config
mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias 
mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core
mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env
mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_rewrite
mod_setenvif mod_status mod_userdir
```

I have tested that my .htaccess is being run using:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Not found TEST"
```

And that 404's with that message. (After I removed that rule) I placed this inside my .htaccess:

```
# http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Short url for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

But still it just 404's when I go to `/wiki/<Anything Here>`

Is anyone able to shed some light as to what could be happening and why it may not be working?

Answer (score 0):

Jesus, after spending ages trying to get this to work finally figured it out, I have no idea why this isnt listed

Putting:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

At the top of my htaccess file did the trick.